# Export data into excel laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, datatable, laravel-datatables

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr style="font-size: 16px;">
        <th>approval_no</th>
        <th>pnr</th>
        <th>airline</th>
        <th>cost</th>
        <th>collected</th>
        <th>due_date</th>
        <th>time_limit</th>
        <th>notes</th>
        <th>approve_laststatus</th>
        <th>customer</th>
        <th>supplier</th>
        <th>created_by</th>
        <th>created_at</th>
        <th>Assignee</th>
        <th>Ticket Number</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
        <th>created_at</th>
        <th>EMD Number</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
        <th>created_at</th>
        <th>Invoice Number</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
        <th>created_at</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($approvals as $approval)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $approval->approval_no }}</td>
            <td>{{ $approval->pnr }}</td>
            <td>{{ $approval->airline->airline }}</td>
            <td>{{ $approval->cost }}</td>
            <td>{{ $approval->collected }}</td>
            <td>{{ date("m/d/Y", strtotime($approval->due_date))}}</td>
            <td>{{ date("m/d/Y", strtotime($approval->time_limit))}}</td>
            <td>{{ $approval->notes }}</td>
            <td>{{ $approval->approve_laststatus}}</td>
            <td>{{ $approval->customer->customer_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $approval->supplier->supplier_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $approval->creator->first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ date("m/d/Y", strtotime($approval->created_at))}}</td>
            <td>{{$approval->assignee}}</td>
        </tr>
        @if(!empty($approval->tickets))
            @foreach($approval->tickets as $ticket)
                    <tr>
                        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                        <td>{{ $ticket->ticket_number }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $ticket->creator->first_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ date("m/d/Y", strtotime($ticket->created_at))}}</td>
                    </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
        @if(!empty($approval->emd))
            @foreach($approval->emd as $emd)
                <tr>
                    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                    <td>{{ $emd->emd_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $emd->creator->first_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ date("m/d/Y", strtotime($emd->created_at))}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
        @if(!empty($approval->invoices))
            @foreach($approval->invoices as $invoice)
                <tr>
                    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                    <td>{{ $invoice->invoice_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $invoice->creator->first_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ date("m/d/Y", strtotime($invoice->created_at))}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Im loading relationship data using laravel export to excel, This is the current code I'm using to show the data in the Excel sheet, I'm using laravel view to get the output. Attached is the output, the nested data print on one row down.
Related data coloured in the same colour.
How can I get the related data to start on the same row?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the related data to start on the same row, you can modify the structure of your HTML table. Currently, you have separate rows for each related data (tickets, emd, invoices) within the main approval row. Instead, you can merge the cells for the related data into a single cell and use colspan to span multiple columns.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style="font-size: 16px;">
            <!-- Header columns -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($approvals as $approval)
        <tr>
            <!-- Main approval data -->
        </tr>
        @if(!empty($approval->tickets))
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Header columns for tickets -->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($approval->tickets as $ticket)
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Ticket data -->
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @if(!empty($approval->emd))
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Header columns for emd -->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($approval->emd as $emd)
                        <tr>
                            <!-- EMD data -->
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @if(!empty($approval->invoices))
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Header columns for invoices -->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($approval->invoices as $invoice)
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Invoice data -->
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Its coming in om same column no on the same row I wanted it in the same row